# How can I populate an Array to use in a nested loop with filenames from a subfolder?

Tags: arrays, bash, nested-loops

I don't use bash very much so bare with me!

I have this while loop that is searching for a certain file name in each folder(myFile.yaml) and then doing a load of stuff. Part of that stuff needs to also involve files (varying number) within a subfolder. I currently have it set up as a for loop that will cycle an array:

```
files=(thisFile.yaml thatfile.yaml otherfile.yaml)
    for file in files do;
        echo "$folder"/"morefiles"/"$value"
    done


>repo/folder1/morefiles/thisFile.yaml
>repo/folder1/morefiles/thatFile.yaml
>repo/folder1/morefiles/otherFile.yaml
>repo/folder1/morefiles/foo.yaml
> etc.
```

This is working as expected but now I need a way to populate `files` with the actual files from the subfolder.

The main folder where `myFile.yaml` sits has the PATH `$folder` so the files are within `"$folder"/"moreFiles"`. I'm happy for `files` to either contain the full path and name or just the filename.

Structure:

```
Repo > Folder1 > myFile.yaml 
Repo > Folder1 > moreFiles > thisFile.yaml 
Repo > Folder1 > moreFiles > thatfile.yaml 
Repo > Folder1 > moreFiles > otherfile.yaml

Repo > Folder2 > myFile.yaml 
Repo > Folder2 > moreFiles > foo.yaml
Repo > Folder2 > moreFiles > barr.yaml 
Repo > Folder2 > moreFiles > foobar.yaml
```

Comment: I find this hard to wrap my head around - could you please post an example directory structure and pseudo-code nested for-loops that demonstrate what you would like to do?

Comment: `I need a way to populate files` Do you really _need to_ have an array with the files? Why not just use the files as they are instead of creating an array? `for file in files do .... This is working as expected` - I doubt that - it's a syntax error. `How can I populate an Array to use in a nested loop` Do you _have to_ use a nested loop? How is the loop "nested"?

Comment: @Thomas is that better?

Comment: `Structure:` Ok, and what do you want to have in your array?

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm more than happy to take advise on a different way to do it. I don't understand what you mean - if I manually populate an array I get the desired output. This is nested as it's all going on inside a while loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the glob.

```
shopt -s nullglob  # just to protect
files=("$folder"/morefiles/*)
```

But if there's no point in storing files, then prefer not to. Just iterate over them.

```
for i in "$folder"/morefiles/* ; do
```

And you can get the same newline-separated output of files with:

```
printf "%s\n" "$folder"/morefiles/*
```

Comment: Note that this will give the path to the files, not just the filenames. That is, you'll get "repo/folder1/morefiles/thisFile.yaml", not just "thisFile.yaml".

Comment: @KamilCuk I know it's out of the scope of the original question but I've just discovered that one of the "morefiles" folders has an additional folder inside containing more files to be checked - is there a way to generalise to ensure subfolder files are also included?

Comment: `"$folder"/morefiles/** "$folder"/morefiles/*` research `bash globstar`. But you would have to filter out directories - anyway, read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and do  `find .... -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r line; do` in complex cases.

Comment: Would be great if I was able to update the bash version on the systems